# Shim prompts "Verification succeeded" on every startup

Tags: bootloader, prompt, dkms

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3, and installed nvidia-384.111. I enabled secure boot in the BIOS, and signed the driver via mokutils.

On reboot, shim prompted to enroll the new MOK. So, nvidia drivers were installed correctly.

However, now, on every startup, shim prompts `Verification succeeded`, and I have to press `Ok` by pressing Enter. Is there a way to stop that (without breaking shim)?

The only resource I have found so far was [the rhboot git repository](https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/master/shim.c), which shows `Verification succeeded` was shown because the `secure_mode` returns True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved this by running `mokutil --set-verbosity false`.